# django-import-export Импорт связей

Tags: python, django, импорт, export

У меня есть 3 модели:

```
#Товары
class Products(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Наименование товара")
    upc_code = models.IntegerField('UPC Код', unique=True,
                            help_text='Проверить <a href="">UPC Код</a>')
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(verbose_name="Количество")
    article = models.CharField(max_length=200,verbose_name="Артикул") 
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name="Входная цена") 
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 

#Коэфициенты на товар для пользователя
class ProductsInstance(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4,
                          help_text="Unique ID")
    product = models.ForeignKey('Products', on_delete=models.RESTRICT, null=True,verbose_name="Наименование товара")
    coeff = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name="Коэффициент")
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True,verbose_name="Заказчик")
    price_for_client = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name="Цена")
    def __str__(self):
        return '{0} | {1}'.format(self.product, self.borrower)
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.price_for_client = self.product.price * self.coeff 
        super(ProductsInstance, self).save(*args, **kwargs) 

#Заказ товаров для пользователя
class ProductsSet(models.Model): 
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, help_text="ID")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    products_set = models.ManyToManyField('ProductsInstance', related_name='sets', blank=True) 
    borrower = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    created_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    total_amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2,verbose_name="Сумма заказа", default=0)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name 
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_amount = sum(product.price_for_client for product in self.products_set.all())
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Поясню, имеется товар(модель Products), к которому привязаны разные коэффициенты для разных пользователей (модель ProductsInstance). [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При формировании заказа выбираются коэффициенты для пользователя(отображены как Название товара | Пользователь)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне необходимо импортировать/экспортировать заказы товаров для пользователей, реализовать решил с помощью модуля django-import-export. Подключил в админке

```
class ProductsSetAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_classes = [ProductsSetImportResource]
    list_display = ('name', 'borrower', 'created_date', 'total_amount')
    fields = [
        'id',
        'name',
        'products_set',
        'created_date',
        'borrower',
        'total_amount',
    ]
    filter_horizontal = ['products_set']
    list_filter = ['borrower', 'created_date']
admin.site.register(ProductsSet, ProductsSetAdmin)

class ProductsSetImportResource(resources.ModelResource ):
    # Определяем поле products_set как поле с множественным выбором,
    # используя виджет ManyToManyWidget с моделью ProductsInstance и полем id
    products_set = fields.Field(
    attribute='products_set', 
    widget=widgets.ManyToManyWidget(ProductsInstance, field='product')
    )
    # Определяем поле borrower как поле с одиночным выбором,
    # используя виджет ForeignKeyWidget с моделью User и полем username
    borrower = fields.Field(
    attribute='borrower',
    widget=widgets.ForeignKeyWidget(User, field='username')
    )
    class Meta:
        # Указываем модель, которая будет импортироваться
        model = ProductsSet
        # Указываем поля, которые будут импортироваться
        fields = ('id','name', 'products_set', 'borrower', 'total_amount')
```

Экспорт срабатывает отлично, я получаю файл
[image: Результат экспорта]
Как мне реализовать импорт заказа в таком же формате как я получил при экспорте?
Т.е. указать только название из товаров(products_set), пользователя(borrower) и название заказа (name). Name и borrower импортируется без проблем, а с полем products_set проблема, при импорте просит указывать id а не имя, и указав id товара (допустим 2) импортируется товар со всеми его коэффициентами для всех пользователей.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот как мне  сделать так, чтобы я указывал имя товара и по имени товара уже искался коэффициент на этот товар для пользователя который указан в borrower и добавлялся в заказ ?